# how to retrive length of the araay of structure (bidarray )?

Tags: solidity, erc-20, ether

```
struct BidInfo {
        uint256 BidId;
        address payable bidder;
        uint256 bidAmount;
    }

    BidInfo[] public _bidInfo;

    mapping(uint256 => BidInfo) bidArray;
```

I am trying to retrive length of bidarray so far I tried using

`bidArray[address].length`

Comment: Please share more of the code so we can help

Comment: f.e what is SelectedID ? is it a struct?

Comment: I have shared whole contract please check now @AvocadoChocolate

Comment: Which array length do you want to get?

Comment: bidarray (which has uint mapped to struct) @AvocadoChocolate

Comment: So you basically want to know how many mappings are in Bidarray?

Comment: yes sir @AvocadoChocolate

Comment: Ok, you cannot do that in Solidity unfortunately. Ill send an answer now how you can work around it

Comment: ohh thx, that means a lot @AvocadoChocolate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as we spoke in the comments, you basically want the amount of mappings in BidArray. Unfortunately you cannot do that in Solidity. Mappings in Solidity are'nt iterable and don't have length.

For you to keep track of this, you can manually declare a state variable and update it whenever you have a push/delete operation on the mapping.

f.e

```
uint256 mapLen;
// addition to the map then
mapLen++;
// deletion to the map then
mapLen--;
```

Comment: yeah I can do this. thx.